# Webdriverio Node.js Mocha Chai test skips describe block

Tags: mocha.js, chai, webdriver-io

I am running this test and it seems that when the test get's to the function portion of my describe block, it skips the whole thing and gives a false positive for passing.

```
// required libraries
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
var describe = require('describe');
var after = require('after');

console.log("Lets begin");

describe('Title Test for google site', function() {

 console.log("MARTY!!");
 // set timeout to 10 seconds
this.timeout(10000);
var driver = {};

console.log("before we start");
// hook to run before tests
before( function (done) {
// load the driver for browser
console.log("before browser");
driver = webdriverio.remote({ desiredCapabilities: {browserName: 'firefox'}       });
 driver.init(done);
});

it('should  load correct page and title', function () {
// load page, then call function()
return driver
.console.log("before site")
  .url('http://www.ggogle.com')
  // get title, then pass title to function()
  .getTitle().then( function (title) {
    // verify title
    (title).should.be.equal("google");
    // uncomment for console debug
    // console.log('Current Page Title: ' + title);
  });
  });
  });
  // a "hook" to run after all tests in this block
  after(function(done) {
   driver.end(done);
  });


  console.log ("Fin");
```

This is the output I get

> Lets begin
>   Fin
>   [Finished in 0.4s]

As you can see it skips everything else.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong and should be removed:

```
var describe = require('describe');
var after = require('after');
```

Mocha's `describe` and `after` are added to the global space of your test files by Mocha. You do not need to import them. Look at all the examples on the Mocha site, you won't find anywhere where they tell you to import `describe` and its siblings.

To get Mocha to add `describe` and its siblings, you need to be running your test through `mocha`. Running `node` directly on a test file won't work. And for `mocha` to be findable it has to be in your `PATH`. If you installed it locally, it is (most likely) not in your `PATH` so you have to give the full path `./node_modules/.bin/mocha`.

Comment: Yeah I had done it that way before and it was outputting that describe and after were not defined.

Comment: node testname.js in iTerminal or I just run the code in Sublime

Comment: That's wrong. You have to use `mocha testname.js` at the command line. I don't know about Sublime.

Comment: When I attempt to use mocha testname.js it says command not found. I have mocha installed in my node_modules folder. I had warnings pop up about Jade changing to pug and then I installed pug. I guess I'll attempt to reinstall everything again.

Comment: Ok, then give the path to the bin that is installed in `./node_modules`, like this: `./node_modules/.bin/mocha testname.js`.

Comment: mine was something along the lines of /node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha. I got the error cannot resolve path (or pattern)

Comment: What platform are you on? OS X? I'm on Linux. `_mocha` exists but it is definitely wrong on Linux. You can do `./node_modules/.bin/mocha` (note that it is `.bin` with a leading dot, easy to miss), or `./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha`. No underscore before `mocha`.

Comment: I'm on OS X. Neither of those examples worked for me. What I posted before was the file location of the mocha in the mocha bin folder. I'm not sure if I installed them incorrectly. I have a selenium folder that I was using as the directory via terminal and I just installed everything in there, which created a large node_modules folder with everything in it every time I installed to the selenium directory.

Comment: So I went to do the npm init and then I cancled it and somehow mocha started to run the test.